# Menu disappear when hover, IE6 bug?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, html, internet-explorer-6

I cannot figure out why the menu disappear in IE6(using version in XP mode of Windows 7) when I

1. hover the paragraph of the main content
2. hover the "Ordinary Members" link

Please see the page in http://preview.hksenet.hk/Home/President and the style sheet of the menu in http://preview.hksenet.hk/Content/sidemenu.css

Anyone can help? Many thanks!

Comment: You're trying to make an HTML5 page work in IE6?

Comment: Sorry, I never got back to you, I was moving and things got lost in the busyness of it all.  Were you able to find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Wow, that's weird!
I don't have an exact answer but here's a couple thoughts.

For me at least, disabling jQuery solved the issue.  HTML Shiv had lots of js errors shown in the console, although none were obviously apparent when loading the page.

My best bet is that jQuery is selecting that image (which makes the menu disappear) triggering some unexpected results.  Maybe given the html shiv errors, it stems from that, as the selectors are off.  Thus making sense of why IE6 is the only culprit. There's a firefox addon, I believe fireQuery, that displays inline javascript events, which should help.  If nothing else seems to be making sense, maybe test in HTML 4, or another to ensure shiv isn't the culprit?

[This python regex](https://gist.github.com/1231583) (you could allays run on online regex tester if need be) removes all html5 elements and turns into div's of that class.  It would be a quick way to rule out the HTML issues

Best of Luck!

Comment: David, thanks for your comment.  How can you disable jQuery and make it work in IE6?  It seem the whole menu disappear when I disable jQuery.  Can you show me some code?  Thanks. @david-hobs